# Timestamp into output filename

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, timestamp

I would like to **insert the timestamp** into an output filename of a python script, for example: `20011231_230159_md5_filelist.csv`

I am having trouble inserting the code.

This is the **end** of the script whose output filename needs to have a timestamp:

```
try:

    my_last_data = get_md5(file_full_path) + ", " + get_last_write_time(file_full_path) + ", " + get_size(
        file_full_path) + ", " + file_full_path + "\n"

    with open("md5_filelist.csv", "a") as my_save_file:
        my_save_file.write(my_last_data)

    print(str(file_full_path) + "  ||| Done")

except:
    print("Error On " + str(file_full_path))
```

This is the timestamping code I am battling with (although not sure if it is the best line for the purpose):

```
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
```

I tried inserting in various ways, does not work. Any hints?

Comment: Did you try `timestr + "md5_filelist.csv"`?

Comment: yes. does not work. `with open(timestr + "md5_filelist.csv", "a") as my_save_file:`

Comment: Do you want to modify the name of an existing file or create a new one with the timestamped name of an existing one?

Comment: How exactly does it "not work"?

Comment: Weird. Although my previous suggestion omits the 2nd underscore, so it should be `timestr + "_md5_filelist.csv"` but that's a trivial detail. What do you mean by "does not work."? That's pretty vague.

Comment: Your latest question update does not answer the questions about how it's not working.

Comment: OK, thank you. your suggestion works, i made a mistake with tabs and space initially when trying out. inserted in **line 35**:  `timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")`, changed on **line 40** `with open(timestr + "_md5_filelist.csv", "a") as my_save_file:` works.

Comment: does it matter which line in the script `timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")` is located?

Comment: @user3026965 it should be before this line `open(timestr + "_md5_filelist.csv", "a") as my_save_file:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @pm-2ring (see comments), the solution:

```
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
(timestr + "_md5_filelist.csv", "a")
```

in the script:

```
try:

    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

    my_last_data = get_md5(file_full_path) + ", " + get_last_write_time(file_full_path) + ", " + get_size(
        file_full_path) + ", " + file_full_path + "\n"

    with open(timestr + "_md5_filelist.csv", "a") as my_save_file:
        my_save_file.write(my_last_data)

    print(str(file_full_path) + "  ||| Done")

except:
    print("Error On " + str(file_full_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need.

```
try:
    my_last_data = get_md5(file_full_path) + ", " + get_last_write_time(file_full_path) + ", " + get_size(
        file_full_path) + ", " + file_full_path + "\n"

    with open("{}md5_filelist.csv".format(timestr), "a") as my_save_file:
        my_save_file.write(my_last_data)

    print(str(file_full_path) + "  ||| Done")
except:
    print("Error On " + str(file_full_path))
```

You were not using timestr anywhere in you code.

Comment: i am getting  'Error On C:\x\stby\1\b.txt' while the original script works fine (but without timestamping the output file).